# D3 TimeParse Formatting

Tags: javascript, d3.js

been working on a D3 assignment and the timeParse is really not working for me.

[image: Console.log Data Format without timeparse]

the attached image is the date data of the csv I'm using (d3.dsv loaded) and I have used `var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m-%d-%Y")` in an effort to load it, but it always returns `null`. I have also tried `(%e-%d-%Y)` variation to no avail. The interesting thing is that the first format worked yesterday and now its giving null when I tried continuing my work today. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not provided that data, I have assumed the data & the code below works.

One thing to pay attention to is in you data you have forward slash (/) separating day, month & year. However, in `d3.timeParse`, you use hyphen (-). Both have to match.

```
let data = [
  { date: "11/22/2016", cat: 5 },
  { date: "12/22/2016", cat: 4 },
  { date: "01/22/2017", cat: 3 },
  { date: "02/22/2017", cat: 2 },
];

parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

data.forEach((d) => console.log(d.date));

data.forEach((d) => (d.date = parseTime(d.date)));

data.forEach((d) => console.log(d.date));

console.log(data);
```

**Output**

[image]